# How many viruses has the average computer?

Tags: malware, antimalware

Malware hides, so you cannot expect your computer to be malware-free, even when you have antivirus.

My computer works fine, but I am fairly sure that I might have something lurking in there. Rootkits or similar. Not because I did anything wrong, but just because it's a computer connected to the internet.

Are there any numbers on this? Statistics or such?

Comment: I honestly like this question, but I feel it's off-topic. It's very broad, and there are a lot of different sources for a lot of different things. I also don't think it's answerable because we don't have the entirety of all malware data, and probably never will.

Comment: there is no "average computer" - Windows, Mac, Linux, versions, protections, user activity - there can't possibly be useful statistics

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's an all-inclusive answer to this statistic, but you may be able to get a feel for it if you compile the numbers that anti-viruses release during their annual security bulletins, such as [Kaspersky's](https://securelist.com/analysis/kaspersky-security-bulletin/73038/kaspersky-security-bulletin-2015-overall-statistics-for-2015/).

And for bonus points, Kespersky has a pretty neat interactive [map](https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/) which includes [statistics](https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/stats/), which is really convenient when management walks by, because it at least makes you look busy, and management likes flashy animations and graphs.